# How to package a WPF app with post build dependencies into UWP package?

Tags: c#, uwp, packaging, desktop-bridge

I am trying to package a wpf application in a UWP package using the C# packaging project. The problem is that my application has dlls dependencies (c++ dlls) that are provided with post build events in its output. So when I add a reference to my application in the packaging project, its output only contains the dlls that are generated from the build of the desktop app - all other dlls (from post build events) are ignored.

Then I decided to make the same post build events for the packaging project and provide the missing dlls, but unfortunately, they were not considered as well by the packaging process.

Is there a way I can force this dlls to be packaged in the result appx?

Comment: How do you process the post build events?

Comment: The desktop app has post post build events that supply the dlls in its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a decision for my situation (not sure it is the best one possible…).

Let’s assume the desktop app’s name is MyApp. The solution contains the following steps:

1. Adding post build event in the desktop app to copy its output to a directory “MyApp” in the packaging project.
2. Include this directory in packaging project and make it to be copied as content.

To make the whole directory as content add the following ItemGroup in packaging project wapproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="MyApp\\**\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This makes the content of the folder to be copied in the output of the packaging project. Since it is with the same name as the referenced app, it is copied in the same output directory, packaging project creates for each referenced app. It seams this happens just in the right time (before calling MakePri.exe) and all the dependencies are considered from the build process of the packaging project.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Yordans answer, if you want to reference a directory outside from the project include the `Link` metadata:

```
<Content Include="..\release\win-unpacked\\**\*.*" Link="app\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```